# Android - Tell if parent activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, ondestroy

So, I have written an app that has a Main activity (A), and various other sub-activities that all do something, report the work back to main, and finish.

What I am running into is that if the user leaves my app at Screens B or C, when they come back at a later time and dalvik has destroyed my activities for more RAM... the app starts back at B or C, and reads all the initialization stuff from the saved intent, and continues on as if nothing happened.   Until they return back to activity A, where we get a force close from unexpected things.

I've twiddled with overriding `onStop()` and calling finish, but i think this is a bit scorched earth, I'd like to let them leave on that activity and come back.  But i'd also like to detect if the underlying main activity has been destroyed, and then destroy my entire activity stack.

From reading around, I get the idea that `onDestroy()` is not always called, so it isnt reliable for me to insert some logic into Activity A's onDestroy....   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting your sub activities B and C with the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).

Comment: Interesting, I haven't messed with intent flags before.  These seem to just replicate the functionality of overriding B and C's `onStop` though (scorched earth), but they do give back some null returns back on the main activity's `onActivityResult` that I could capture for persistence....  I'll tinker with some other flags that look promising and report back.

Comment: I still couldnt get it to work as imagined, but I did learn a good deal about intent flags in the process so ill mark it as correct.  I ended up going the scorched-earth route (override onStop, call `finish();`) because leaving my data in an inconsistent state just wasnt acceptable.